# Google MaPs API v3 marker to lightbox within map-canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building my personal website to showcase my portfolio of coding examples to prospective employers. One very simple project is a way to showcase all my travels. I want a static google maps, with markers on all the places I've visited (Taiwan, Japan, Hawaii, France, bunch of cities in US...etc).

Upon clicking on these markers, I want a popup overlay box to appear on top of the map, covering say 70% of the map, centered, with the outer edges of the map greyed out. Clicking anywhere in the greyed area will close the popup overlay.
These popups will contain a picture of my travels, as well as short quote or blurb or an anecdote.

This sounds simple enough, but I cannot seem to get the popup overlay to behave how I want.
I found plenty of examples on the web as to how to add these markers and have an infoWindow open, but they don't do what I want them to do :

1) the infowindows appear as speech balloons either to the top, left, right, or bottom of the marker
2) this shifts my map
3) I don't know how to grey out my map upon activation of the popup overlay

Can someone point me in the right direction? Should I be using just CSS/Javascript/jQuery to accomplish this? Is there anything I can use from the Google Maps API? I have some basic knowledge of Angular, and would love to get better at it. Is Angular applicable here? Any help is appreciated.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Travels</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 375px;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 1,                                        // zoom level
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41,0)        //center of map
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var taipeiContent = 'I Love Taipei!';
            var parisContent = 'I Love Paris!';
            var newyorkContent = 'I Love New York!';


            var locations = [      
                ['taipei', 25.0333, 121.6333, taipeiContent],
                ['paris', 48.8567, 2.3508, parisContent],
                ['newyork', 40.7127, 74.0059, newyorkContent],
            ];

            //function setMarkers (map, locations) {
                var marker, i;
                var markers = new Array();
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    maxWidth:300
                });
                for ( i=0; i<locations.length;i++ ) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        title: locations[i][0],
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker, i){ 
                        return function() {

                        infoWindow.setContent(locations[i][3]);
                        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                        }
                    })(marker,i));
                }
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {infoWindow.close();});
            //}
        }
        window.onload = initialize;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

--Edit-- I know NY appears in Kyrgyzstan, but thats not important right now.

Comment: You mean like [this example using colorbox](http://jsfiddle.net/mPBXe/69/) from [this question: Google map displaying in jquery pop up window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597797/google-map-displaying-in-jquery-pop-up-window)

Comment: @geocodezip Thats not what I want, thanks for trying. What I want is a map with markers. upon clicking a marker, a smaller box will appear over the map, centered, with the map greyed out. what appears in the smaller box is an image and some text about the marker I just clicked on. Most applications have the box coming directly above the marker, and i dont know how to grey out the map.

Comment: @geocodezip after further digging, i've realized the term I need to use is "lightbox." I want my click on a marker to open a lightbox instead of an infowindow.