# How to create google map popup?

Tags: google-maps, popup, popupwindow

I have read following SO answer:
[Google map displaying in jquery pop up window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13597832/2674303)

But problem that it is not popup it is redirect to another page, but I want popup.

Can you help me change this code according my requirements?

### UPDATE

```
<a class="googleMapPopUp" rel="nofollow" href="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=south+australia" target="_blank">View location map </a>​

$('.googleMapPopUp').each(function() {
    var thisPopup = $(this);
    thisPopup.colorbox({
        iframe: true,
        innerWidth: 400,
        innerHeight: 300,
        opacity: 0.7,
        href: thisPopup.attr('href') + '&ie=UTF8&t=h&output=embed'
    });
});​
```

example:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mPBXe/1/)

### update

this code doesn't work too

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
</head>
<body>


<a href="#" onclick="WinOp();" title="show" >show map</a>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">


function WinOp()
{   popup = window.open("", "", "height=300, width=700, top=300, left=300, scrollbars=1")    
    popup.document.write('<div id="map-canvas"></div>')
    popup.document.close()
    return false;
}

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</html>
```

because `document.getElementById('map-canvas')` returns null

Comment: What does your code look like? Have your read the [documentation on InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip topic updated

Comment: @geocodezip your first exampe about when you have a map and if you click somewhere you will seee infoWindow. My question a bit different. My html  page have href link. I want that When user click on href he see modal window and this window contains map.

Comment: I get a javascript errors on your fiddle: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js`, `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` (on `thisPopup.colorbox()` because the external script has not been loaded)

Comment: try this please http://jsfiddle.net/mPBXe/95/embedded/result/  it is working foor me

Comment: I still see `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function fiddle.jshell.net/:32` in the (Chrome) javascript console.

Comment: I don't know... I use chrome too

Comment: [This URL](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js) doesn't work to include the colorbox script.

Comment: Yes, you are right but anyway it works. But I want to see popup instead of new page

Comment: I suspect that issue is why you aren't seeing the popup...

Comment: If I change that URL to [one that works](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js), [the fiddle opens a colorbox for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mPBXe/96/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including the colorbox external library.  This URL doesn't work:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js

This one does:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPBXe/96/)

```
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```